# Boolean Algebra: $a+a'b = a+ab = a$?

Tags: boolean-algebra

$a(a'+b) = aa'+a'b = a'b$ ($aa' = 0$ in any case)

$a+a'b = 1a + a(a'+b) = a(1+a'+b) = a$

$a+ab = a(a+b) = a => a+a'b = a+ab$

However, when I use truth table to compare the result of $a+a'b$ to $a+ab$

when $a = 0, b = 1$

$a+ab = 0$ while $a+a'b = 1$.

What is the mistake I made here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your mistake is at the very first step, where you wrote
$$a(a'+b)=aa'+a'b.$$
That should be
$$a(a'+b)=aa'+ab.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$a + a'b = a + ab = a$$
This is not correct.  So $$a + ab = a$$
$$a + ab = a(1 + b) = a$$
This is correct.  But $$a + a'b ≠ a$$
The a' is redundant.
$$a + a'b = a(1 + b) + a'b = a + ab + a'b = a + b (a + a') = a + b$$
$$a + a'b = a + b$$
$$a + ab = a ≠ a + a'b$$

Also:  In your first step you do $a(a'+b) = aa'+a'b = a'b$.  This is correct, but I do not understand where $a(a'+b)$ came from.  It is not in your starting question.  You can multiply a term by 1 because X' + X = 1, but you cannot multiply a term by whatever.  The rules have to satisfy boolean algebra.

Was this ( $a(a'+b)$ ) in the original question?  Clarify and someone can help.